# Validate separate forms with one function - this input

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, this

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/Lxvzuznt/13/

It's a simple single form with jquery validation.

-

I need to have more than one form on the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/47Lxamq7/7/

The forms are created dynamically so I'd like the id's of the input fields to be the same.

The different forms will sign up users to different events so they will capture the same information but for different use.

Is there a way to use one validation function and say validate the input related to 'this' button

```
    $(function(){
        $('.btn').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(valFields()){

            }
        })
    })

    function valFields(){

        var flag = true;

        var name = $(this).parent().$('#name');
        var number = $(this).parent().$('#number');

        if(name.val().length == 0){
            alert('No Name');
        }

        if(number.val().length == 0){
            alert('No Number');
        }

        return flag;
    }
```

Comment: Note that ID should be unique in the whole document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#id
You can create ID like "name-1", where digit is the number of the form

Comment: My typo sorry it should have been classes in the second exmaple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@zaynetro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311760/validate-separate-forms-with-one-function-this-input/26312099#comment41290464_26311760) mentioned, you cannot have same ids within the same page.  So you can either use `class` or `name` attributes of `input` elements.

Better pass the `this` in `valFields` method and then access it elements by its `class` name like

```
var name = $(ele).parent().find('.form-control');
var number = $(ele).parent().find('.form-control');
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // pass this
    if (valFields(this)) {

    }
  })
})

// Access the this here
function valFields(ele) {
  var flag = true;

  var name = $(ele).parent().find('.form-control');
  var number = $(ele).parent().find('.form-control');

  if (name.val().length == 0) {
    alert('No Name');
  }

  if (number.val().length == 0) {
    alert('No Number');
  }

  return flag;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="number" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <button class="btn">Send</button>
</form>
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="number" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <button class="btn">Send</button>
</form>
```